# LaTeX, índices de contenidos como elementos genéricos

Tags: latex, indices, genericos

Estoy realizando un documento el cuál tiene un índice de contenidos que es igual al de otros documentos y quisiera usarlo tal cual, en éstos, de forma similar a la siguiente;

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12 pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\input{./IndiceGenericofichero}

\input{./fichero1}
\input{./fichero2}

\end{document}
```

El contenido de fichero1 y fichero2 podría ser, respectivamente, los siguientes;

```
\section{1ª sección}
TEXTO, TEXTO, TEXTO Y MÁS TEXTO.
\subsection{subsección}
TEXTO DE LA SUBSECCIÓN, TEXTO, TEXTO Y MÁS TEXTO EN LA SUBSECCIÓN.
```

```
\section{2ª sección}
TEXTO, TEXTO, TEXTO Y MÁS TEXTO.
```

Sin embargo solo he encontrado tres maneras de hacer el fichero IndiceGenericofichero y son las siguientes;

```
\tableofcontents
\section{1ª sección}
\subsection{subsección}
\section{2ª sección}
```

Esta primera forma junto con las entradas de fichero1 y fichero2 devolvería el siguiente documento;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde las entradas al índice de contenido se duplican luego no es correcto el resultado. La segunda forma sería;

```
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{1ª sección}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{subsección}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{2ª sección}
```

Y el resultado sería;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aunque sé que podría evitar las entradas duplicadas al índice de contenidos añadiendo un '*' en las declaraciones de las secciones y de la subsección en los ficheros fichero1 y fichero2, y aunque prefiero la enumeración de las entradas del índice de contenidos. La cuestión es que esta forma no me vale y la razón es que me obliga a añadir el contenido de los documentos justo después de cada una de las declaraciones "\addcontentsline{}{}{}", ya que a partir de éstas se marca la página del contenido en el índice de contenidos. Si no se hace las referencias a las páginas serán inconsistentes y si se hace es igual que escribir todo el documento de manera monolítica.

La tercera y última manera, la más simple, es simplemente lo siguiente;

```
\tableofcontents
```

Que devuelve el siguiente documento como resultado;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este resultado, de entre todos, es el que si es correcto... sin embargo me vale de nada ya que pierdo por completo la generalidad del fichero IndiceGenericoFichero.

Mi cuestión es, por lo tanto, ¿hay alguna forma de lograrlo que no implique complejas definiciones de nuevos comandos?.

Comment: Pues no entiendo qué pretendes. La forma correcta de generar el índice es la tercera, como dices, pero no sé a qué te refieres con que pierdes la generalidad de IndiceGenericoFichero. Más bien todo lo contrario, ese fichero es completamente general en el sentido de que puedes usarlo tal cual en cualquier otro proyecto de similar estructura, pues adaptará su contenido a las secciones/subsecciones que realmente tengan el resto de ficheros. ¿O lo que pretendes es poner el mismo índice en todos aunque "sea falso"?

Comment: Si y no, si es esa mi intención y no lo es porque no es pretender ello aunque "sea falso" sino pretenderlo para ahorrarme tener que revisar continuamente cuales son los títulos de las secciones y subsecciones... Aunque si, tal vez mi propuesta sea un atraparse la cola todo el tiempo.

Comment: Creo que sigo sin entender nada, pero... ¿quizás te interese echar un vistazo al fichero de extensión `.toc` que tienes en esa misma carpeta?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar con:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12 pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoc,enumitem,tocloft} % necesarios para el IndiceGenericofichero.tex
\let \savenumberline \numberline
\def \numberline#1{\savenumberline{#1.}} % necesario para escribir un '.' despues de cada enumeración

\begin{document}

\input{./IndiceGenericofichero}

\input{./fichero1}
\input{./fichero2}

\end{document}
```

Con el siguiente archivo (`fichero1.tex` y `fichero2.tex` son iguales a los que pusiste):

```
% IndiceGenericofichero.tex
\begingroup
    \etocsetstyle{section}%
                 {\begin{enumerate}[label=,left= -\parindent .. 0pt]}%
                 {\normalsize\bfseries\item}{\etocname \hfill \etocpage}%
                 {\end{enumerate}}
    \etocsetstyle{subsection}%
                 {\begin{enumerate}[label=,itemsep=0pt,topsep=0pt,left= 0pt]}%
                 {\normalfont\item}{\etocname \cftdotfill{\cftdotsep} \hbox to 5mm{\hss\etocpage} }%
                 {\end{enumerate}}
    \tableofcontents
    \endgroup
    \vspace{-18mm}
    \renewcommand*\contentsname{}
\tableofcontents
```

Obteniendo:

[image: resultado]

Referencias:

- [`The etoc package docs`](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/etoc/etoc.pdf)
- [`The tocloft package docs`](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf)
- [`enumitem package docs`](https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf)